# BMP reader not functioning correctly

Tags: c++, binary-data, bmp

I wrote a small BMP loader for 24-bit BMP, and it works, except it does not display the colors. Everything is grayscale with bits of color (not the correct ones) here and there. The loader for my code is below

```
void BMP::Read(char* filename)
{
    FILE* f;
    unsigned char info[54];
    if ((f = fopen(filename, "rb")) == NULL) return;
    fread(info, sizeof(unsigned char), 54, f);
    m_width = *(int*)&info[18];
    m_height = *(int*)&info[22];
    m_size = 3* m_width * m_height;
    m_pdata = new unsigned char[m_size];
    fread(m_pdata, sizeof(unsigned char), m_size, f);
    fclose(f);
}
```

I then access the array using the following formula:

```
red = m_pdata[(y * m_width + x) + 2];
blue = m_pdata[(y * m_width + x) + 0];
green = m_pdata[(y * m_width + x) + 1];
```

Any suggestions here? I think the problem is in the load function, but not sure.

Comment: use a debugger - look at the contents of m_pdata - does it look right?

Comment: second - what happens to red,blue,green how do you display them?

Comment: Duplicate of lots of similar questions, for example  [Strange values when reading pixels from 24-bit bitmap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19624159/strange-values-when-reading-pixels-from-24-bit-bitmap)

Comment: You forgot the factor: `4 * (y * m_width + x) + 0` (or `3 * …`, dunno).

Comment: There's probably padding at the end of each row that you are not accounting for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to include the pixel width when extracting the pixel channels:

```
int pixel_width = 3; // 3 bytes for 24 bit
```

According to [Strange values when reading pixels from 24-bit bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19645119/369450), there's also padding at the end of each row. The padding can be calculated by:

```
int row_padding = (4 - (m_width * pixel_width) % 4) % 4;
```

The final resulting formula to access the pixel color channels would be:

```
red = m_pdata[(y * m_width + x) * pixel_width + y * row_padding + 2];
blue = m_pdata[(y * m_width + x) * pixel_width + y * row_padding + 0];
green = m_pdata[(y * m_width + x) * pixel_width + y * row_padding + 1];
```

Since rows have padding, your calculation of `m_size` is slightly too small. You can account for the row padding as:

```
m_size = pixel_width * m_width * m_height + row_padding * m_height;
```

Comment: Close, but not quite. The padding is actually `3 - ((m_width * pixel_width) % 4)`

Comment: @StevenDon Actually, the padding should be `(4 - (m_width * pixel_width) % 4) % 4` (I'm sure there's a simpler formula but it works).

Comment: Ah yes. You're right. I'm more used to calculating the stride: `((m_width * pixel_width) + 3) & ~3`